# create function from graph/from limits

Tags: limits, functions

I am a Calculus I student and we are into our second week and finishing up limits.

I know how to create a graph from limits, and I know that for example a parabola would match with a quadratic function and a piecewise graph might match with a rational expression with absolute value, for instance.

Our assignment is to "sketch a function" based on simple facts such as $$f(1)=2$$ 
and
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow1} f(x)=-2 $$

How do we convert graphs to fractions? I can easily visualize a graph, but that how I should be going about this? Can anyone throw down an example for my simple case and many another? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

These conditions don't uniquely determine a function. Your instructor probably wants you to experiment with visualizing different functions. The easier one here is

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}-2 &\text{if }x\neq 1;\\
2 &\text{if }x=1.
\end{cases}
$$

However, you could also get creative. In particular, you can take any function with the property $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}=-2$, but then create a new piecewise function by making $f(1)=2$.

A less trivial example is

$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}-2+(x-1)\sin (x-1) &\text{if }x\neq 1;\\
2 &\text{if }x=1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Very good reply, you are right about the intentions of the instructor and the goal of the assignment. Your first example is plenty to get me started. What if I run into a nasty set of requirements such as a specific domain, $$lim f(x) = undefined$$ or $$f(2) = undefined$$. Is it all intuitive if I understand graphs of limits, or are there any gotchas you can help me with?

Comment: Know that when you define a function you also define the domain. It is enough to say that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\neq 2$, and the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{2\}$ (the set of all numbers except $2$).

Comment: are there any available resources that can help me learn where to start when I see various combinations such as: f(x) = undefined, limits = dne, or examples such as f(3) = 4 & limx->4 = 4?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the instructions on how to make such a graph.

1. Draw a horizontal line whose equation is $y = -2$, but at the point $(1,-2)$ make a hole.
2. Plot the point $(1,2)$ with a darkened circle.

After this, you have made such a graph.

Also from this graph, you can write a function:

$f(x) = -2$, if $x \neq 1$, and $f(1) = 2$.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Will mark and upvote solved when enough rep.